# How to print Myanmar Unicode Font at EPSON Receipt Printer with Android Java?

Tags: java, android

When I tried to print Myanmar Unicode font with Android Java for Epson receipt printer, only question mark display. Anyone know how to print.

Here is my code:

```
String method = ""; 
StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder(); 
String mmText = "ဘြဲ႕ ဘယ္လိုရခဲ့ပါလိမ့္"; 
mmText = URLEncoder.encode(mmText, "US-ASCII");
textData.append(mmText + " 9.99 R\n"); 
textData.append("410 3 CUP BLK TEAPOT 9.99 R\n");
method = "addText"; 
method = "addCut"; 
mPrinter.addCut(Printer.CUT_FEED);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Two possibilities:  1) you have gotten the output encoding method wrong, 2) the printer doesn't have Myanmar font capability.

Comment: @StephenC Is there anyway to check printer font capability? Thanks

Comment: You could read the documentation for the printer ....

Comment: @StephenC Thank you. Do you have any sample code to do encoding method?

Comment: Please post your code that shows the way you are currently trying to do it.

Comment: String method           = "";
        StringBuilder textData  = new StringBuilder();   
            String mmText       = "ဘြဲ႕ ဘယ္လိုရခဲ့ပါလိမ့္";
            mmText              = URLEncoder.encode(mmText, "US-ASCII");

            textData.append(mmText + "  9.99 R\n");
            textData.append("410 3 CUP BLK TEAPOT    9.99 R\n");
            method = "addText";
            method = "addCut";
            mPrinter.addCut(Printer.CUT_FEED);

Comment: @StephenC I just checked documentations, printer do not have myanmar font Capability. Is there any idea to add myanmar font capability? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry but the code in your comment doesn't make any sense to me, and I can't see how it prints *anything*.   Please update your Question with your real code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is any solution to this.  Your code doesn't make a lot of sense, but has given me some clues:

- You are apparently using the Epson EPOS SDK for Android.
- The weird `method = ...` assignments are borrowed from example code, where the `method` variable is being used to print error messages in an enclosing exception handler.

Looking at the SDK reference manual, it is rather difficult to work out how you are supposed to use it.  The `addText` is actually sending text to the printer, and it is apparently converting the string to something that the printer understands.   The problem is ... what does it understand?

The `addTextLang` is apparently how you are supposed to select the language or encoding (the doc uses both terms!) to use when talking to the printer.    Apparently, your printer's technical documentation should tell you which languages are supported.

If the printer doesn't support the language, you are probably out of luck.  From what I can tell, it is the SDK / driver converts the Unicode code points to values in a code table.  The printer that converts codes in the code table to glyphs.  If the printer doesn't understand the code table for a given language, it won't be able to generate the glyphs to print.  (My guess is that the SDK is using a Java `Charset` to do the Unicode to code-table encoding, and the question marks are the `Charset`'s way of saying "there is no mapping".

Another possibility would be to do your own Unicode string to bitmap rendering, and use addImage to print the image.